# Consolidating projects spread out on different VMs under central directory

Tags: .net, tfs, version-control, project-management

I have .NET projects spread out on different Windows Server VMs. For instance couple of VMs have some web projects, another VM has some projects who's output is scheduled processes, and then there are some production VMs having production code and development VM having development code.

Developers have admin access on these VMs and connect via mapped drives or via RDP.

I'm trying to get out of this kind of setup and want to

1. bring all projects under a central directory
2. start using TFS.

I've installed TFS. Before I can do "Add solution to source control" in Visual Studio, I would like to bring all projects to a central location on file system. I tried using a network share but `web.config` keeps getting locked in VS after few minutes of opening the solution - regardless of what solution it is - even a brand new solution.

Where exactly should this central directory reside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change your thinking a bit to understand how source control systems work and how to properly adopt them.

TFS **is** the central repository.  Every developer has a local copy of the code, and they synch their changes with TFS using source control operations (e.g. check in, get latest, etc).

So to get your code in TFS, just grab a copy of everything to your computer (just a local folder, no network shares), then check it all in to TFS.  Other developers will then do a Get Latest to get their own personal copy of the code on their machines.

Comment: so once an existing project is added to TFS the folder under which it is residing has no relevance anymore? and i can delete it and use TFS as my primary source of the project, checked out to local drive when needed?

Comment: now that I have created a solution collection in TFS, added a solution to the collection - i need to create a new project in that existing solution. When i try to do that it asks me the location on hard disk where this will be created. So i need to create a project on disk first and then add it to TFS? can't i directly create it in TFS?